# SendFile over TCP/IP .NET CF

Tags: c#, printing, tcp, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I would like to send a file ("Label.prn") from a Windows Mobile 6.5 Device to a printer.
This happens over TCP/IP.
I have realized this application as a test on a normal Desktop-Client. It is very simple and easy. Just send the file over the TCP Socket and the printer does its job.

Here is the desktop client demo (works just fine):

> private void buttonSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>
> ```
>     {
>         TcpClient client = new TcpClient(AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
>         client.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.5"), 6101);
>         if (client.Connected)
>         {
>             client.Client.SendFile("C:\\Label.prn");
>             client.Close();
>         }
>     }
> ```

Now I want to do the same on the mobile part. The problem is: There is no `SendFile()` method!

This is how I tried to solve it. It either fails with an Exception "The connection was closed by the printer" or it just executes the code, but nothing happens.
Have you got any suggestions? Maybe I'm doing something wrong. How can I send a file over a TCP Socket on .NET CF 3.5?

Here the code sample:

> ```
>  Exception returnException = new Exception("The file could not be sent to the printer!");
>  TcpClient client = null;
>
>         try
>         {
>             FileStream fs = new FileStream(strFilePath, FileMode.Open);
>             StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fs);
>
>
>             string strBuffer = reader.ReadToEnd();
>
>             strBuffer = PrinterHelper.FillTestInformations(strBuffer);
>
>             byte[] array = new byte[strBuffer.Length];
>             array = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strBuffer);
>
>             //Tried manually and with ASCII-Encoding.
>             //for (int n = 0; n < strBuffer.Length; n++)
>             //{
>
>             //    array[n] = Convert.ToByte(strBuffer[n]);
>             //}
>
>             client = new TcpClient();
>             client.Connect(IPAddress.Parse(strIP), nPort);
>
>             // Gets executed but nothing seems to happen.
>             client.GetStream().Write(array, 0, array.Length);
>
>             // Exception!
>             //client.Client.Send(array, array.Length, SocketFlags.None);
>         }
>         catch (Exception ex)
>         {
>             returnException = new Exception("The label could not be printed!", ex);
>         }
>         finally
>         {
>             try
>             {
>                 client.Close();
>             }
>             catch
>             {
>
>             }
>         }
> ```

Comment: Is `array` the same size, in bytes, as the file and as you expect?  If you walk the array or bytes, does it match what you see in the file contents?  Pay close attention to line endings and the like.

Comment: Yes, watch your step. "Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes" will only convert to 7bit ASCII (as the US knows). If there are any ASCII codes below 0x20 or above 0x7F these will get lost. Normally you have to read the file as binary into a byte array (chunk by chunk) and then send the byte array (if large, then also using chunks of about 1400 bytes).

Comment: I have tried it with the 'for' loop. Shouldn't it be ok if I use that method? josef, you said "read the file as binary". Do you mean from the StreamReader or after the 'ReadToEnd()' Method?
I really have no idea what else I can do. I don't know if I'm even doing it right. I might be missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve this issue. Apparently it was an error with the Length of the string passed.

I initialized my byte array like this:

> byte[] array = new byte[strBuffer.Length];

The problem is that the string.Length wasn't accurate.  If I initialize the Byte array implicit then the problem doesn't occur.

> byte[] array = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strBuffer);

Thanks for the support. I hope this helps other people trying to solve the issue.

Following is the new code:

> ```
> FileStream fs = new FileStream(strFilePath, FileMode.Open);
> StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fs);
> string strBuffer = reader.ReadToEnd();
> reader.Close();
>
> strBuffer = PrinterHelper.FillTestInformations(strBuffer);
>
> byte[] array = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strBuffer);
> client = new TcpClient(AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
> client.Connect(IPAddress.Parse(strIP), nPort);
> client.GetStream().Write(array, 0, array.Length);
> client.Close();
> ```

Comment: Remember that ASCII encoding is only 7 bit! Better use UTF8 or any known code page as ISO-Latin-1.